# How to transform input coordinates in 2D Orthographic projection?

Tags: opengl, matrix, graphics, glm-math

I generate the transformation matrix by the glm::ortho function.
I want the origin in the middle,[EDIT] x axis to the right, y to the up.[/EDIT]

That works fine when drawing stuff, but whenever I get a mouse input from the Window, (0,0) is at the top left.

What is the general way of handling this transformation?
I am now using a very ad-hoc and hacky way.

```
    y= sizey-y;
    x-=sizex/2;
    y-=sizey/2;
```

Comment: The coordinates you describe are impossible using only a projection matrix. The X-axis is horizontal and the Y-axis is vertical. You need a view matrix in order to change the orientation of your pre-transformed coordinates.

Comment: I do not think so, but I will try... you want Y to point to the right and X to point up. Projection by itself cannot do that, you need to rotate your coordinates 90 degrees around the Z-axis to do that. But rotation is not part of a projection matrix built with glm::ortho, that is the responsibility of your view matrix. You ***can*** multiply the two things together to produce 1 matrix, but then you actually have multiple transformations and it is no longer purely a projection matrix.

Comment: Okay, so I have to derive the view matrix from the ortho matrix?
That should be as obtuse as my current method. I was looking for some clever solution involving inverses ..etc. :(

Comment: No, the two are completely separate. The fundamental problem here is that in clip-/NDC-/window-space the Y-axis is always vertical and the X-axis is horizontal. I honestly do not know why you want to rotate your coordinates 90 degrees like this if you are trying to match mouse coordinates -- they use a horizontal X-axis and vertical Y-axis.

Comment: Oh my god, that was a mistake. Sorry for that, y up x right convention is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The general way to handle this would be:

```
Translate (-sizex/2, sizey/2, 0.0); // Y translation:  -sizey/2 + sizey = sizey/2
Scale     ( 1.0,        -1.0, 1.0);
```

#### This produces the following matrix:

```
|1.0  0.0 0.0 0.0|   |1.0 0.0 0.0 -sizex/2|     |1.0  0.0 0.0 -sizex/2|
|0.0 -1.0 0.0 0.0| * |0.0 1.0 0.0  sizey/2|  =  |0.0 -1.0 0.0 -sizey/2|
|0.0  0.0 1.0 0.0|   |0.0 0.0 1.0   0.0   |     |0.0  0.0 1.0    0.0  |
|0.0  0.0 0.0 1.0|   |0.0 0.0 0.0   1.0   |     |0.0  0.0 0.0    1.0  |
```

You can multiply your input coordinates by that matrix to transform them, but what you had originally in your question is much simpler.

Comment: By general, I meant, suppose I change my choice to another coordinate system later. How can I avoid doing this manually again?

Comment: If you want to get technical, you could actually derive this transformation from your viewport and projection matrix. This is effectively unprojecting the coordinates, and that is a well-defined process that `glm` can assist you with using a function literally called `unProject`. Again, it is overkill since that involves a *lot* more computation, but it would work in every case. The trick would be to use an *identity* matrix for `model` when you call that function, and I would suggest using `win.z` = **-1.0** (or whatever value you used for your near plane when you made the projection matrix).